# Tracking HTML5 Web App installs on iOS devices

Tags: ios, html, iphone-standalone-web-app

We recently launched an HTML5 Web App (using JQuery Mobile), which has a slide down box encouraging users to bookmark the Web App on their home screens.  Users can do this from Safari by clicking Bookmark and then "Add to Home Screen".  Any thoughts on how we might be able to track the number of "installs".  I don't believe we can add any tracking to the native iOS bookmarking behavior from within the HTML5 Web app.

Thanks

Comment: Not tried it, but [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1950-Detecting-iPhone-s-App-Mode-Full-Screen-Mode-For-Web-Applications.htm) looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can get an event whenever the user installs the web app on their homescreen. *However*, you can know if the user is in 'full screen' / 'web app' mode by checking the `window.navigator.standalone` property in Javascript. So you might be able to do a call to your statistics provider and provide them the standalone property as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can at least detect whether the app is launched from the homescreen or via browser via the `window.navigator.standalone` flag. You could use it in combination with cookies or localstorage to ensure you count unique installs in your backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to store the result of `window.navigator.standalone` into Google Analytics